# how to use if / else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a google script beginner and i need some help !
I have a script importing data in a file and I want to add a condition on the date.

My script below:

```
obj.participants[i].create_date.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/, function(p, year, mon, day, hour, min) {
                data[index][3] = [day, mon, year - 2000].join("/");
                data[index][4] = [hour, min].join("h");
            });
billet = obj.participants[i].id_weez_ticket;
data[index][31] = 15+billet.substring(0,4);
```

I want to change the last line depending on the date value in data[index][4]:

- if data[index][4] < 1/09/2015 then data[index][31] = 15+billet.substring(0,4)
- else data[index][31] = 16+billet.substring(0,4);

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Franck, this question is receiving "close votes", because it is not clear what you're asking. Since you have an answer that seems to have helped you understand something, I suggest spending a few minutes to clarify the question (especially the title) to make it something that future readers may find and learn from when they have a similar problem.

Comment: I am asking how to compare a date with a reference date in an if / else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this, but this wouldn't work as data[index][4] is going to be a time in the form '[hh]h[mm]'.

```
if (data[index][4] < 1/09/2015) {

    data[index][31] = 15+billet.substring(0,4);

} else { 

   data[index][31] = 16+billet.substring(0,4);
}
```

data[index][3] contains the date, and then you'll have to convert them into time objects, and then into milliseconds before you can compare them.

```
var referenceDateMs = new Date(2015, 9, 1).getTime()
var dateMs = (new Date(year, mon, day))..getTime()

if (dateMs < referenceDateMs) {

    // ....

} else {

    // ....
}
```

Comment: In fact it doesn't work ... because I get a ReferenceError: "year" is not defined. And the same for "mon" and  "day". And I don't understand why. Franck

Comment: That'll be an issue in your wider code. If you share the script with me (andrewr1969 at gmail dot com) I could take a look.

Comment: Andrew thank you, it works well now. Troubleshooting with the dates is very common and you understand the problem, despite the question that was not very clear!